# Error message => Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)' Found this candidate Problem of casting Array of Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, subscript

I don't know if it the problem, but I have Alamofire in my project, and when I add FireBase to my project, I have this error message:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

```
 if let json = ((try?  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]) as [String : AnyObject]??),
                            var models = json!["models"] as? [AnyObject]
                        {
                            if (models.count >= 1 && models[0].name != "")
                            {
                                print(modelItems)
                            }
                            if (models.count > 1)
                            {
                                models = (models as! [[String:Any]]).sorted(by: { (dictOne, dictTwo) -> Bool in
                                    let d1 = dictOne["name"]! as! String
                                    let d2 = dictTwo["name"]! as! String
                                    
                                    return d1 < d2
                                }) as [AnyObject]
                            }
                            
                            for model in models
                            {
                                if let slots = model["slots"] as? [AnyObject],
                                    let idModel = model["id"] as? Int,
                                    let description = model["description"] as? String,
                                    let name = model["name"] as? String
                                {
...
```

Is there any conflict?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shim Yep, it is good, I put *[Dictionary<String, Any>]* it is equivalent I think. Many thanks. You can put your answer, I will validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `models` as `[AnyObject]` i.e. an array of `AnyObject`. So `model` is an instance of `AnyObject` and the compiler wouldn't be able to infer what it is and thus it can't be subscripted without a more specific type.

Should work if you use a new variable with type `[[String: Any]]`.

`[Dictionary<String,Any>]` is equivalent, but to me the shorter syntax is more readable.